# C++ nlohmann JSON get name of array

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I have nlohmann json object:

```
json uuid = R"(
                 {
                    "uuid": ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
                 }
              )"_json;
```

I can get the values in array without problems:  str = uuid["uuid"][0];

But how can i get array name himself ?

Comment: Do you actually need the name or do you just want to iterate through the values?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the underlying map from the json object which gives you the array names and the arrays. If you just want to iterate through the items that's easy as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <json.hpp>

using json = nlohmann::json;

int main()
{
    json uuid = R"(
                 {
                    "uuid": ["aaa","bbb","ccc"],
                    "uuie": ["aaa","bbb","ccc"],
                    "uuif": ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
                 }
              )"_json;

    if (uuid.is_object())
    {
        auto obj = uuid.get<json::object_t>();
        for (auto& kvp : obj)
        {
            std::cout << kvp.first << ":" << kvp.second << "\n";
        }
    }

    for (auto& item : uuid)
    {
        std::cout << item << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```